# `npm install` ends with "Killed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to run [Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope) (a meteor app) on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. I follow the instructions in the readme:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
git clone git@github.com:TelescopeJS/Telescope.git
npm install
```

The first two commands run without an error, but the last command end in `Killed`:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
extract:moment → gunzTarP ▐ ╢█████████████████████████████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░╟
Killed
```

Since it doesn't give any information I'm unsure what could be wrong here. Does anybody know how I can solve this? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Using the tip of @Mills in the comments I first ran `npm install cross-spawn` and then `npm install` again. This fixed the `npm install` issue, but when I now try to run the app using `meteor` it ends with "Killed" again:

```
$ meteor
Killednloading meteor-tool@1.3.2_4...        |
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: looks like cross-spawn-async is deprecated try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn instead

Comment: @Mills - I'm not very familiar with npm. Could you explain a bit more on how I can do that?

Comment: trying running `npm install cross-spawn` and then `npm install` again to see if that works. It looks like whats happening is when you run npm install npm looks inside your package.json provided by telesope and is running a deprecated package

Comment: It did indeed solve that issue. Thanks for that. But when I now try to run the app using `meteor`, it ends in "Killed" again. Any ideas?

Comment: What did the error message say before it gave you the "killed" output? Looks to me like opening an issue on the telescope repo might be best because the build process shouldn't be this broken.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I am running into a similar issue installing npm packages and getting the message "Killed" and a non-zero exit status. For my scenario, it was because my system was running out of memory and I had no swap configured. Configuring swap fixed my problem.

Comment: I was running a vagrant box with default settings (512MB in RAM). Adding 2 cpus and 1024MB RAM fixed this for me.

Comment: I limited the resource of my docker container. Unreal. Adding `memswap_limit` fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: facing the same issue in docker just reduce container memory and its works

Comment: I followed this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04 for setting swap on ubuntu, although it seems a bit old. So far so good.

Comment: @zakariaamine [this DigitalOcean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04) is the updated version (for Ubuntu 18.04) of the article you linked to

Comment: I resized my shared machine RAM and helped it. Thanks

Answer (score 142):

I haved same problem, my solution:

```
  sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
  sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
  sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

this commands changed configuration for swap

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me. I use the Digital Ocean minimum server ( 512 MB ) and this solution worked for me.

Comment: free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7938        4968         278          92        2690        2594
Swap:          5119           2        5117
after this i have run npm install command but i got
 sudo npm install
npm WARN deprecated ng2-filter-pipe@0.1.10: Use ngx-filter-pipe instead.
npm WARN deprecated typings@2.1.1: Typings is deprecated in favor of NPM @types -- see README for more information
Killed ............] / fetchMetadata: sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/webpack-subresource-integrity

Comment: Hello Shiva!
Please post your package.json

Comment: Thank you so much, In t2.nano AWS EC2 configuration it worked.

Comment: Perfect. Worked for my Ubuntu LTS 18.4 on AWS Lighsail. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you worked for Ubuntu 18.04 on EC2 !

Comment: Tested on t4g.nano, works for ARM / graviton

Comment: That worked for me. I got chmod errors on the last command but it still worked.

Comment: Thank you worked for me on alibaba SWAS ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked for Digital Ocean basic droplet as well. Thanks alot

Answer (score 20):

To solve this issue on 14.04 and 16.04:

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo swapon --show
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
echo 'vm.swappiness=10' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50
echo 'vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

This will create a swap file of 1GB

Comment: What if I only have 512 mb of ram on server?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue when running `npm run build` in a VM with a single core CPU and 1GB RAM. Increasing the RAM to 4GB resolved this issue.

Comment: This works for me but I only had to upgrade to 1CPU 2GB RAM and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Trying `running npm install cross-spawn` and then `npm install` again to see if that works. It looks like whats happening is when you run npm install npm looks inside your package.json provided by telesope and is running a deprecated package

Answer (score 1):

or you can do the hardway do npm install somewhere else. i did it on my windows and uploaded al the nodemodules dir with ftpclient to the server. that worked for me

Comment: That's not going to work in some situations. Some Node modules include binary components which may be system-dependent. (For an obvious example: `node_modules` from a Linux system will not be portable to Windows, and vice versa.)

Comment: Also, node_modules is a gargantuan folder of thousands of files, this transfer would not be very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is correct, error is indeed because of memory limits, but if you are using npm in cloud and/or its not feasible for you to increase RAM or SWAP memory, try using `yarn` to install packages instead of `npm`.