# Npm install not working in Alpine Linux Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, npm, alpine-linux

I am in an Alpine Linux Docker container and when I try to run `npm install`, npm hangs and kills itself! This is what the last line in the npm log looks like: https://imgur.com/T8KIojJ

Things I've tried:

- clearing the cache,
- excluding optional dependencies, and
- there is no package-lock.json in the folder.

Comment: It may was running out of memory. I found some solutions in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127667/npm-install-ends-with-killed. Hope it's hellfull.

Comment: Does it just print out a URL, or are there more log messages?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve] and the actual error, in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your Docker container might not have enough memory or CPU resources to complete the `npm install` command. Possible solutions

1. Allocate More Memory and CPU:
   When you run your Docker container, you can specify the amount of memory and CPU it can use with the -m and --cpus flags. For example:

```
docker run -m 512m --cpus 2.0 your-image-name
```

2. The "Killed" message you're seeing is typically a sign that the npm process is being terminated by the system's Out-of-Memory (OOM) Killer. more context [here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/dev-oom-killer.html)

You might need to paste more information about your yml configuration